# canvas bottom missing uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

I have a Canvas /RelativePanel which I'm using as background "image" in my uwp app.

How can I position a child in the canvas at the bottom? There is no canvas.bottom AP like in wpf. I also didn't find any proper attached property in the relativepanel to position the child at the bottom of the relative panel.

```
        <RelativePanel>
            <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource AsterioidTemplate}" />
            <Canvas x:Name="mountain_to_bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Path Width="126.389" Height="326.227" Canvas.Left="272.433" Canvas.Top="28.3291" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.33333" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF23232D" Fill="#FF23232D" Data="F1 M 398.155,353.889L 273.099,186.024L 315.298,28.9958L 398.155,353.889 Z "/>
            </Canvas>
        </RelativePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I position a child in the canvas at the bottom?

[Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas) is a layout panel that supports absolute positioning of child elements relative to the top left corner of the canvas in uwp.You control the positioning of elements inside the Canvas by specifying x and y coordinates.Since canvas is absolute positioning , child content is not constrained by the bounds of the panel, so we may not define the child at the bottom of canvas directly. But we can try to calculate the position manually to let the child position at the bottom of canvas. For example, the following demo can show the image at the bottom of the canvas.

XAML Code

```
<Canvas  Background="Pink"  x:Name="mountain_to_bottom" Height="600">
    <Path x:Name="pathelement" Width="126.389" Height="326.227" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.33333" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF23232D" Fill="#FF23232D" Data="F1 M 398.155,353.889L 273.099,186.024L 315.298,28.9958L 398.155,353.889 Z "/>
</Canvas> 
<Button x:Name="btnbottom" Click="btnbottom_Click" Content="to bottom"></Button>
```

Code behind

```
  private void btnbottom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {  
      double canvasheight = mountain_to_bottom.ActualHeight;
      if (pathelement.ActualHeight < canvasheight)
      {
          double top = canvasheight - pathelement.ActualHeight;
          pathelement.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, top);
      }
  }
```

> I also didn't find any proper attached property in the relativepanel to position the child at the bottom of the relative panel.

Inside [relative panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RelativePanel), elements are positioned using a variety of attached properties. Relative panel provides [RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.alignbottomwithpanel) attached property for position the child at the bottom of the panel.

```
 <RelativePanel BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="10">
     <Path x:Name="pathelement" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"  Width="126.389" Height="326.227" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"   Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.33333" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF23232D" Fill="#FF23232D" Data="F1 M 398.155,353.889L 273.099,186.024L 315.298,28.9958L 398.155,353.889 Z "/>
 </RelativePanel>
```

If canvas and relative panel can not meet your requirements well you can consider about other containers. What container to use depend on your layout. For example, relativePanel is a layout container that is useful for creating UIs that do not have a clear linear pattern; that is, layouts that are not fundamentally stacked, wrapped, or tabular, where you might naturally use a StackPanel or Grid. More details please reference [Layout panels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels).